# Implement a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am working in rails. If I send a request like http://www.example.com/titles/search?search_text=something
as a respond I need a Json .How to implement this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a response in JSON format then you need to pass your request as url.json format.
In your controller, inside that action check your request format and return the result according to the requested format. You can read more about this here and having example source code as wel. Check it out here [Rendering JSON and other formats.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
  format.json {    
    render :json => @your_obj.to_json, :callback => params[:callback], :content_type => "text/html" }
    format.xml { render :xml => response }
  end
```

Comment: If I send a request like www.example.com/titles?search_text=sheldon 
my response should be like

book
{
titles
[{
   title:book1
   author:sidney
    image-url : xxx.jpg
  }
  {
   title:book2
   author:sidney
    image-url : yyy.jpg
  }
]
}
In my controller I created a function and accessed the search text using params.I dont know how to create the json file and send that  json to client.

Comment: you have no need to create any json file and send it to server/client.   Just change the your url  www.example.com/titles.json?search_text=sheldon thats it. And in above my code put your result_list(in ur case its books) in place of @your_obj. This is right way to achieve what you want.

Comment: If don't want to go in that way, so copy the same code and put inside format.html {"put code here"} what i have suggested above and your task is done. This time you don't need to change ur request url.

Answer (score 0):

In your titles contoller in particular action, having a `search_text` as get param use
`render json: @object`
detailed: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render (2.2.8)